# Android Youtube API JSON-C parsing with GSON

Tags: android, json, youtube, gson

i'm trying to devolop an Android app to retrieve videos for a specific user and i would like to use the JSON-C response format to keep size low. Once i get my response is in the format:

```
{
"apiVersion":"2.1",
"data":{
    "updated":"2012-12-02T14:40:07.424Z",
    "totalItems":175,
    "startIndex":1,
    "itemsPerPage":25,
    "items":[
        {
            "id":"rnzJ5x3sWyk",
            "uploaded":"2012-12-01T20:19:07.000Z",
            "updated":"2012-12-01T20:19:07.000Z",
            "uploader":"user",
            "category":"News",
            "title":"L'ALLUVIONE HA DISTRUTTO LE ROULOTTE DELLE VACANZE",
            "description":"Ad Albinia,in un rimessaggio per roulotte, il proprietario, i volontari e i vacanzieri che sono soliti passare l'estate qui, si sono rimboccati le maniche per ripulire dal fango le tante \"case delle vacanze\" distrutte dall'alluvione",
            "thumbnail":{
                "sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/rnzJ5x3sWyk/default.jpg",
                "hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/rnzJ5x3sWyk/hqdefault.jpg"
            },
            "player":{
                "default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnzJ5x3sWyk&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                "mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=rnzJ5x3sWyk"
            },
            "content":{
                "5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/rnzJ5x3sWyk?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata",
                "1":"rtsp://v1.cache2.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwkpW-wd58l8rhMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                "6":"rtsp://v6.cache2.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwkpW-wd58l8rhMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
            },
            "duration":136,
            "viewCount":2,
            "favoriteCount":0,
            "commentCount":0,
            "accessControl":{
                "comment":"allowed",
                "commentVote":"allowed",
                "videoRespond":"moderated",
                "rate":"allowed",
                "embed":"allowed",
                "list":"allowed",
                "autoPlay":"allowed",
                "syndicate":"allowed"
            }
        },
and others items....
```

When i setup my model classes to deserialize it how it should look like
Do i have to include all elements , even those i'm not interested in?

```
 public class SearchResponse {

    public Container data;

  }
```

which refers to

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Container {

public ArrayList<Items> results;

@SerializedName("totalItems")
public int totalItems;

@SerializedName("startIndex")
public int startIndex;

@SerializedName("itemsPerPage")
      public int itemsPerPage;
}
```

and for each item:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Items {

@SerializedName("id")
public String id;

@SerializedName("uploaded")
public String uploaded;

@SerializedName("category")
public String category;

@SerializedName("title")
public String title;

@SerializedName("description")
public String description;

public Thumbnail thumbnail;

@SerializedName("duration")
public int duration;


}
```

and for each Thumbnail

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Thumbnail {

@SerializedName("sqdefault")
      public String sqdefault;

@SerializedName("hqdefault")
public String hqdefault;

}
```

I think is that "data" section which is killing me.

Could anybody help please or give me some examples if you have already done this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
public ArrayList<Items> results;
```

Needs to be:

```
public ArrayList<Items> items;
```

or:

```
@SerializedName("items") public ArrayList<Items> results;
```

And it should work fine.

And no, you do not have to have all fields present in your POJO. Any fields present in the JSON that you don't have will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use GSON, you could do it yourself - keep it simple and learn some JSON yourself :-)

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/

https://github.com/blundell/YouTubeUserFeed

Here's an extract:

```
 // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(youTubeJsonResult);

        // Get are search result items
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");

        // Create a list to store are videos in
        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();
        // Loop round our JSON list of videos creating Video objects to use within our app
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // The title of the video
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            // The url link back to YouTube, this checks if it has a mobile url
            // if it doesnt it gets the standard url
            String url;
            try {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            }
            // A url to the thumbnail image of the video
            // We will use this later to get an image using a Custom ImageView
            // Found here http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/
            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");

            // Create the video object and add it to our list
            videos.add(new Video(title, url, thumbUrl));
        }
```

Video is just:

```
public class Video {
    String title;
    String url;
    String thumbUrl
}
```

Comment: Thanks Blundell for your answer. I red your tutorial but i also red somewhere else that JSON parser is much heavier than GSON. Your solution is straightforward and easy to implement, but i was wondering how to do it with GSON.

Comment: @FabrizioFab I would say JSON is more lightweight than pulling in the GSON library. Make your own mind up, here's a reference: http://www.martinadamek.com/2011/02/04/json-parsers-performance-on-android-with-warmup-and-multiple-iterations/

Comment: i will consider your suggestion and try to work with it. Just for learning purposes, how should i declare my model classes to accomodate the JSON-C youtube response to be used with GSON?

Comment: @FabrizioFab why don't you try just declaring the fields you want first, see if it works and if it doesn't then you know you'll need to type all the fields (i doubt you'll need this)